# question on transferring codes, what method should I use?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Question explaination: as some of the comments suggested, I will try my best to make this question clearer. The inputs are from a file and the code is just one example. Supposedly the code should work for any inputs in the format. I understand that I need to use `Scanner` to read the file. The question would be what code do I use to get to the output.

Input Specification:
The first line of input contains the number N, which is the number of lines that follow. The next
N lines will contain at least one and at most 80 characters, none of which are spaces.

Output Specification:
Output will be N lines. Line i of the output will be the encoding of the line i + 1 of the input.
The encoding of a line will be a sequence of pairs, separated by a space, where each pair is an
integer (representing the number of times the character appears consecutively) followed by a space,
followed by the character.

```
Sample Input
4
+++===!!!!
777777......TTTTTTTTTTTT
(AABBC)
3.1415555
Output for Sample Input
3 + 3 = 4 !
6 7 6 . 12 T
1 ( 2 A 2 B 1 C 1 )
1 3 1 . 1 1 1 4 1 1 4 5
```

I have only posted two questions so far, and I don't quite understand the standard of a "good" question and a "bad" question? Can someone explain why this is a bad question? Appreciate it!

Comment: This is not the best question for three reasons that I can see. First is that you did not ask a specific question, but rather you merely state that you're having problems. Second, you did not put your source code in the question body. And third, there should also be a clear example of input and desired output texts.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your output was there.

Comment: @NomadMaker The explaination is pretty clear. For example, in line 2, the code  `+++` is outputted as `3 +`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete working code here try it.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CharTask {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> lines = null;
        try {
            File file = new File("inp.txt");
            FileInputStream ins =new FileInputStream(file);
            Scanner scanner  = new Scanner(ins);
            lines = new ArrayList<String>();
            while(scanner.hasNext()) {
                lines.add(scanner.nextLine());
            }
            
            List<String> output = processInput(lines);
            for (int i=1;i<output.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(output.get(i));
            }
            
            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
    private static List<String> processInput(List<String> lines){
        
        List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String line: lines) {
            output.add(getProcessLine(line));
        }
        
        return output;
        
        
    }
    
    private static String getProcessLine(String line) {
        if(line.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        
        String output = "";
        char prev = line.charAt(0);
        int count = 1;
        for(int i=1;i<line.length();i++) {
            
         char c = line.charAt(i);
         if (c == prev) {
             count = count +1;
         }
         else {
             output = output + " "+count + " "+prev;
             prev = c;
             count = 1;
         }
        }
        output = output + " "+count+" "+prev; 
        
        return output;
    }
    
    
}
```

## Input

(inp.txt)

```
4
+++===!!!!
777777......TTTTTTTTTTTT
(AABBC)
3.1415555
```

## Output

```
 3 + 3 = 4 !
 6 7 6 . 12 T
 1 ( 2 A 2 B 1 C 1 )
 1 3 1 . 1 1 1 4 1 1 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two different problems you need to address, and I think it is going to help you to address them separately. The first is to read in the input. It's not clear to me whether you are going to prompt for it and whether it is coming from the console or a file or what exactly. For that you will want to initialize a scanner, use nextInt to get the number of lines, call nextLine() to clear the rest of that line and then run a for loop from 0 up to the number of lines, reading the next line (using nextLine()) into a String variable. To make sure that is working well, I would suggest printing out the unaltered string and see if what is coming out is what is going in.

The other task is to convert a given input String into the desired output String. You can work on that independently, then pull things back together later. You will want a method that takes in a string and returns a string. You can test it by passing the sample Strings and seeing if it gives you back the desired output strings. Set the result="". Looping over the characters in the String using charAt, it will want variables for the currentCharacter and currentCount, and when the character changes or the end of the string is encountered, concatenate the number and character onto the string and reset the character count and current character as needed. Outside the loop, return the result.

Once the two tasks are solved, pull them together by printing out what the method returns for the input string as opposed to the input string itself.

I think that gives you direction on the method to use. It's not a full-blown solution, but that's not what you requested or needed.